# iPad TCP Connection Socket timed out (Code 60)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am trying to make a simple TCP socket connection from an iPad.

I got a set of code up and running using the simulator and it works fine.

But when I run this code on the iPad it fails.

Heres the code...

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.1.10", 19997, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

The code hangs on [inputStream open];  then I get the error:

```
    The Operation Couldn't be completed.  Operation timed out.  Code 60.
```

Am I missing something simple here?  iOS permissions or something?  Why would it work on the Simulator?  I am new to iOS development.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try adding them to the run loop before you opened the streams? 

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

I'm posting from my phone so sorry for not properly formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code on my iPhone and it works fine. The 'other end' of the connection might be a problem though.

You should test the same code with www.google.com port 80.

Also you could test it in another project or at another 'point' in your project. Maybe there is a problem with 'where you call the code'

You should also consider just using an existing framework for these connections instead of writing everything yourself.

I use Google Async Sockets for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are correct, it was on the server end.